# Hardy's inequality again

Tags: analysis, inequality

How can I prove that the constant in classical Hardy's inequality is optimal?

$$\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(s)ds\right)^p dx\leq \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^p\int_0^{\infty}(f(x))^pdx,$$
where $f\geq0$ and $f\in L^p(0,\infty)$.

This inequality fails for $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ ?

Comment: You may want to look at this, especially Davide's answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83946/hardys-inequality-for-integrals/95399#95399

Answer (score 6):

In this form you need $p > 1.$ For the constant, take small $\epsilon > 0$ and define $$  f(x) = x^{(-1/p) - \epsilon}, \; \; x \geq 1  $$
but $$ f(x) = 0, \; 0 \leq x < 1.  $$

Comment: To find this function, you can equate the integrands, take the $p$-th root, multiply through by $x$ and differentiate with respect to $x$. This yields a differential equation with solution $x^{-1/p}$. Then you just need to take functions in $L^p(0,\infty)$ that are arbitrarily close to that.

Comment: @joriki, it was much easier than that, to find this function I just looked at page 243 in Hardy, Littlewood, and Polya, Inequalities.

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$