# an integral inequality from "Inequality" by Hardy,Littlewood and Polya Chapter7

Tags: integration, integral-inequality

If $f\in C^1[0,1)$ and $f(0)=0$ , show that $\int_0^1\frac{|f(x)|^2}{x^2}dx\leq4\int_0^1|f^{'}(x)|^2dx$

The book solves the problem using variational method.
But I want to seek for an elementary solution for it. Any idea?

Comment: It seems that it is an special condition of famous Hardy's inequality.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126889/121671. This may provide the solution you are looking for by match the right terms.

Comment: Thanks! @Oliver Díaz