# Hardy's Inequality: Problems $3.14$ and $3.15$ in Rudin's RCA

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

In Problem $3.14$, we prove (a) Hardy's inequality, (b) the condition for equality, and I shall talk about (c), (d) below. Problem $3.15$ is the *discrete case* of Hardy's inequality. I have asked three *related* questions in a single post itself, since all of them are related to **Hardy's inequality**, and none should be too involved.

There are some existing posts on MSE related to these topics, so I shall link them right away and point out that my question is not a duplicate: [Post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83946/hardys-inequality-for-integrals), [Post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99392/hardys-inequality-again?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Post 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44456/various-proofs-of-hardys-inequality?rq=1), [Post 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126889/computing-the-best-constant-in-classical-hardys-inequality).

---

For the sake of mentioning it, Hardy's inequality is: For $p\in (1,\infty)$, $f\in L^p((0,\infty))$ relative to the Lebesgue measure, and $$F(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)\ dt\quad (0 < x < \infty)$$ we have $$\|F\|_p \le \frac{p}{p-1} \|f\|_p$$

---

**Question 1:** This is Problem $3.14(c)$ in Rudin's book.

> Prove that the constant $p/(p-1)$ cannot be replaced by a smaller one.

In one of the linked posts, there is some discussion on how this is the **best** constant, but I was unable to follow it. My sense is that it suffices to find a counterexample, i.e. *for every constant* $\beta$ smaller than $p/(p-1)$, we need a function $f_\beta\in L^p((0,\infty))$ which does not satisfy the required inequality. Why are we complicating things? If I'm thinking right, could someone help me find a *counterexample*?

**Question 2:** This appears as Problem $3.14(d)$ of Rudin's book. The author is trying to emphasize that the inequality is not for $p = 1$.

> If $f > 0$ and $f\in L^1$, prove that $F\notin L^1$.

I found an example, $f(x) = e^{-x}$. Then $F(x) = \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$. $F$'s integral diverges, since the integral of $1/x$ diverges (use limit comparison test for integrals). However, as @David C. Ullrich pointed out, this is not enough.

**Question 3:** This is Problem $3.15$ in the same book and is the discrete case of Hardy's inequality.

> Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers. Prove that $$\sum_{N=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right)^p \le \left(\frac{p}{p-1} \right)^p \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^p$$ if $1 < p < \infty$. If $a_n\ge a_{n+1}$, the result can be made to follow from Hardy's inequality. This special case implies the general one.

I took $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \mathbf{1}_{[n,n+1]}$. Then $f\in L^p$ only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^p_n < \infty$. If $f\notin L^p$, the inequality is trivial. So let's take $f\in L^p$. Now using Hardy's inequality, we have $\|F\|_p \le \frac{p}{p-1} \|f\|_p$. What is $F$? $$F(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\mathbf{1}_{[n,n+1]}(t)\ dt = \frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} a_n + (x - \lfloor x\rfloor)a_{\lfloor x\rfloor + 1} \right)$$
How do I proceed?

---

P.S. I have already solved Problems $3.14(a)$ and $3.14(b)$, i.e. proving Hardy's inequality and showing that equality holds iff $f = 0$ a.e.

Comment: Regarding your first question, your idea is reasonable, but not quite right. You need to show that given *any* constant less than $p/(p-1)$, there's a counterexample.

Comment: @Bungo That's what I wanted to write - somehow typed wrongly. I have corrected it now. $f_\beta$ depends on $\beta$. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @OliverDiaz I had linked that post too. I am not familiar with Hardy transforms which you have used. Maybe I don't understand your solution well, but did you find $f_\beta$ for every $\beta < \frac{p}{p-1}$?

Comment: Regarding the second question, the tail of your proposed $F(x)$ looks like $1/x$ for large $x$, hence $\int_1^{\infty}|F(x)|\ dx = \infty$ Therefore irrespective of what happens on the interval $[0,1]$, we must have $\int_0^{\infty}|F(x)|\ dx = \infty$ as well.

Comment: Just a bypasser comment: This question has a great layout, other MSE users should learn from you!

Comment: @QiZhu Almost all my questions follow this layout/format - thank you!

Comment: @Bungo: not quite so (your first suggestion) it is enough to show that the bound $\frac{p}{p-1}$ is *almost* attained by functions in $L_p$ of norm $1$. For then, whenever  $c<p/(p-1)$, then $c<\|H(f)\|_p \approx\frac{p}{p-1}$, where $Hf=\frac{1}{x}\int^x_0f$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Ah, you are correct, good observation. Thanks! I'll leave the earlier comment intact even at the risk of confusion, because the OP had responded to it and I don't want to create even more confusion!

Comment: For Q2 it's not enough to find one example; you're supposed to show that if $f$ is _any_ strictly positive $L^1$ function then $F\notin L^1$.

Comment: Oops, you're right! How would you do that? @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: it's very simple; see answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May details are left to you. The important part is that you review Post 4 where they show why $p/(p-1)$ is the best contact in Hardy's inequality. I give a brief explanation (but do not re do any of the constructions there) of why this is the case.

---

**Question 1:** The answers to the [Post 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126889/121671) (one of which follow the Hint of your textbook) gives the optimal bound in Hardy's inequality. To see this, notice that each solution there ***explicitly*** constructs a sequence of functions  $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset L_p$, such that

1. $\|f_n\|_p=1$,
2. and $\lim_n\|Hf_n\|_p=\frac{p}{p-1}$.

If the bound $p/(p-1)$ were not optimal, and say $\|Hf\|_p\leq c\|f\|_p$ for all $f\in L_p$, for some constant  $c<\frac{p}{p-1}$, then for any of the sequences built in the aforementioned posting, you would have  that
$$c\|f_n\|=c\geq \|Hf_n\|_p\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{p}{p-1}$$
which is a contradiction to $c<p/(p-1)$.

---

**Question 3:** suppose $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a monotone non increasing sequence of positive numbers  such that $\sum_na^p_n<\infty$, and define $f$ as
$$
f(x):=\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n\mathbb{1}_{(n-1,n]}(x)$$
and consider the Hardy transform $Hf$ of  $f$, i.e., $Hf(x):=\frac1x\int^x_0f(t)\,dt$
Then
$$Hf(x)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
a_1 &\text{if}&0<x\leq1\\
\tfrac{a_1+\ldots + a_n+(x-n)a_{n+1}}{x} & \text{if} &1\leq n<x\leq n+1
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$
The assumption on $a_n$ implies that for $1\leq n<x\leq n+1$
$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_1+\ldots + a_n+(x-n)a_{n+1}}{x}&=\frac{(a_1-a_{n+1})+\ldots +(a_n-a_{n+1})}{x}+a_{n+1}\\
&\geq \frac{a_1+\ldots+ a_n-na_{n+1}}{n+1} +a_{n+1}=\frac{a_1+\ldots + a_{n+1}}{n+1}
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0(Hf)^p&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\int^{n+1}_n(Hf)^p\\
&\geq\sum^\infty_{n=0}\Big(\frac1{n+1}\sum^{n+1}_{k=1}a_k\Big)^p
=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\Big(\frac1{n}\sum^{n}_{k=1}a_k\Big)^p
\end{align}$$
Provided you have proved Hardy's inequality for $L_p((0,\infty),\mathscr{B}((0,\infty),\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue's measure,  then
The conclusion of Question 2 follows for the special case $0\leq a_{n+1}\leq a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

See if you can get the general case ($a_n\geq0$ and $\sum^\infty_{n=1}a^p_n<\infty$) from this (consider for example finite segments of $a_n$, that is $b^{(m)}_n=a_n\mathbb{1}_{(0,m]}(n)$ and apply the result to a "reordering" of $b^{(m)}$).

---

**Question 2:** As David C. Ulrich mentioned in his comment and answer, the problem asks to show that $Hf\notin L_1(0,\infty)$ for all $f\in L_1(0,\infty)$ with $f>0$. Here is a proof using Fubini's theorem. Since $g(t, x)=\frac{1}{x}f(t)\mathbb{1}_{(0,x]}(t)\geq0\,$ and  measurable in $(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$,  one can iterate integrals to get
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\int^x_0\frac{1}{x}f(t)\,dt\,dx&=\int^\infty_0\int^\infty_t\frac{1}{x}f(t)\,dx\,dt=\int^\infty_0f(t)\int^\infty_t\frac{1}{x}\,dx\,dt=\infty
\end{align}
A simpler proof is given by David C. Ulrich [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4180795/121671)

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks! I understand Q1 and Q2. Your answer on Post 4 explains it well. Working on the last one now.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: have you completed your study of question 3?

Comment: To elaborate, here's what I'm trying to do:
$$\sum_{N=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N b_n \right)^p \le \sum_{N=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right)^p \le \left(\frac{p}{p-1} \right)^{p} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^p =  \left(\frac{p}{p-1} \right)^{p} \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n^p$$
where $\{b_n\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers, and $\{a_n\}$ is *the* reordering of $\{b_n\}$ such that $a_n \ge a_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: The above (first) inequality should intuitively hold since $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing and we are summing up "larger terms" "more times", but it doesn't seem easy to put this down formally. I think the intuition is clear to me though, please confirm. Thanks!

Comment: I think our $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s are swapped.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: Notice that I am not reordering the whole sequence $a$, but only the first $m$-terms (the reminder terms I set to $0$). Borrowing notation from Statistics, let $a^(m)_1\geq a^{(m)}_2\geq\ldots\geq a^{(m)}_m\geq0$ be the decreasing reordering of the first $m$-terms of $a$, and set $a^{(m)}_k=0$ for $k>m$. Apply Hardy's inequality to this sequence and notice that $\frac{1}{k}\sum^k_{j=1}a_j\leq\frac{1}{k}\sum^k_{j=1}a^{(m)}_j$ for all $1\leq k\leq m$ (***to be continued***)

Comment: @epsilon-emperor:...Then, for any $m$, we get
$$\begin{align}
\sum^m_{k=1}\Big(\frac{1}{k}\sum^k_{j=1}a_j\Big)^p&\leq\sum^m_{k=1}\Big(\frac{1}{k}\sum^k_{j=1}a^{(m)}_j\Big)^p\leq\sum^\infty_{k=1}\Big(\frac{1}{k}\sum^k_{j=1}a^{(m)}_j\Big)^p\\
&\leq\big(\frac{p}{p-1}\big)^p\sum^\infty_{k=1}(a^{(m)}_j)^p=\big(\frac{p}{p-1}\big)^p\sum^m_{k=1}(a^{(m)}_j)^p=\big(\frac{p}{p-1}\big)^p\sum^m_{k=1}a^p_j
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, perfect, that's exactly my reasoning too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

People seem to be misinterpreting Q2. It says

> > If $f > 0$ and $f\in L^1$, prove that $F\notin L^1$.

You can't do *that* by giving an example. Luckily it's
trivial:

Since $f>0$ some elementary measure theory(see below) shows that there exists a *bounded* set $E$ with $m(E)>0$ and a $\delta>0$ so $f\ge\delta$ on $E$. Hence if $x>\sup E$ we have $$F(x)=\frac1x\int_0^x f
\ge\frac1x\int_E\delta=\frac{\delta m(E)}{x},$$so $F\notin L^1$.

### Below

(**edit**) If $f(x)>0$ there exists $n\in\Bbb N$ with $f(x)>1/n$; hence $$(0,\infty)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n,$$ where $$I_n=\{x:f(x)>1/n\}.$$So countable additivity shows there exists $n_0$ with $$m(I_{n_0})>0.$$
Again, $$I_{n_0}=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty(I_{n_0}\cap(0,k)),$$so we can let $E=I_{n_0}\cap(0,k)$ for a suitable $k$; any choice of $k$ gives a bounded set on which $f>\delta>0$, and if $k$ is large enough then $m(E)>0$.

Comment: I don't think that's right. Haven't thought about it much, since a direct proof is very simple (see edit coming soon), but there are problems with exactly what you mean by "$f<\delta$ on $E$". The negation of the lemma has just "there exists $x\in E$ with $f(x)<\delta$", but it _seems_ to me that in the rest of the argument you're assuming $f(x)<\delta$ for  _all_ $x\in E$.

Comment: All you really need is $f\ge 0$ and $m(f>0)>0$. In this case there is a $\delta>0$ and a bounded measurable set $E$ with $m(E)>0$ and $E\subset\{f\ge\delta\}$, in which case $F(x)\ge \delta m(E)/x$ for all $x>\sup E$.

Answer (score 0):

Here another approach to question 1, finding simple counter-examples.

Given $a>p$, let's define this function :
$$f_a(x)=x^{-1/a}\times\chi_{(0,1]}(x)$$
where $\chi_{(0,1]}(x)=1$ if $x\in(0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise.

Then
$$(\lVert f_a\rVert_p)^p=\int_0^1x^{-p/a}dx=\dfrac{a}{a-p}
$$
Let's compute $F_a$.

if $x\ge 1$ :
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
F_a(x)&=\dfrac{1}{x}\int_0^xt^{-1/a}dt\\\\
&=\dfrac{a}{a-1}x^{-1/a}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

if $x>1$ :
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
F_a(x)&=\dfrac{1}{x}\int_0^1t^{-1/a}dt\\\\
&=\dfrac{a}{a-1}x^{-1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Thus

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(\lVert F_a\lVert_p)^p&=\left(\dfrac{a}{a-1}\right)^p \left(\int_0^1x^{-p/a}dx+\int_1^{+\infty}x^{-p}dx\right)\\\\
&=\left(\dfrac{a}{a-1}\right)^p\left(\dfrac{a}{a-p}+\dfrac{1}{p-1}\right)\\\\
=&\left(\dfrac{a}{a-1}\right)^p\left(\dfrac{p(a-1)}{(a-p)(p-1)}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

And now we can compute
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left(\dfrac{\lVert F_a\rVert_p}{\lVert f_a\rVert_p}\right)^p&=
\left(\dfrac{a}{a-1}\right)^p\left(\dfrac{p(a-1)}{(a-p)(p-1)}\right)\times\dfrac{a-p}{a}\\\\
&=\left(\dfrac{a}{a-1}\right)^{p-1}\times \dfrac{p}{p-1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

The function $\varphi : x\mapsto \dfrac{x}{x-1}$ is decreasing. Thus the last equality allows, as $a>p$ :
$$
\dfrac{\lVert F_a\rVert_p}{\lVert f_a\rVert_p}\ge \dfrac{a}{a-1}
$$

For any $\varepsilon>0$, as $\varphi$ is continuous, there exists $a>p$ such as
$$
\dfrac{a}{a-1}>\dfrac{p}{p-1}-\varepsilon
$$

So finally, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $f_a$ function so that $\lVert F_a\rVert_p>\left(\dfrac{p}{p-1}-\varepsilon\right)\lVert f_a\rVert_p$

Thus  $\dfrac{p}{p-1}$ is the smallest constant.