# Check proof that $\int_0^\infty\left(\int_x^\infty|f(t)|dt\right)^px^{b-1}dx\le\left(\frac pb\right)^p\int_0^\infty|f(t)|^pt^{p+b-1}dt$

Tags: proof-verification, lp-spaces

Let $0<b<\infty$ and $1\le p<\infty$. Show that

$$\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_{x}^{\infty}|f(t)|dt\bigg)^{p}x^{b-1}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}\le\frac{p}{b}\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(t)|^{p}t^{p+b-1}dt\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Here is me attempt :

\begin{align}
\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_{x}^{\infty} |f(t)|dt\bigg)^{p}x^{b-1}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}&=\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_{x}^{\infty} x^{\frac{b-1}{p}}|f(t)|dt\bigg)^{p}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
&=\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{\frac{b-1}{p}+1}~|f(xt)|dt\bigg)^{p}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
&\le \int_{1}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{p+b-1}|f(xt)|^{p}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}dt\\
&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty} (xt)^{p+b-1}\frac{1}{t^{p+b-1}}|f(xt)|^{p}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}dt\\
&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty} \eta^{p+b-1}\frac{1}{t^{p+b-1}}|f(\eta)|^{p}~\frac{d\eta}{t}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}dt\\
&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty} \eta^{p+b-1}\frac{1}{t^{p+b}}|f(\eta)|^{p}~d\eta\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}dt\\
&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^{1+\frac{b}{p}}}~dt\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty} \eta^{p+b-1}|f(\eta)|^{p}~d\eta\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
&=\frac{p}{b}\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty} \eta^{p+b-1}|f(\eta)|^{p}~d\eta\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
\end{align}

,where $\eta=xt$ and hence $dx=\frac{d\eta}{t}$ and the first inequality is according to the integral form of Minkowski's inequality.

If you have the time , please checking my proof for validity. Any valuable suggestion and advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the so called Hardy inequality and your answer seems perfectly done to me you find another way [to prove it here page 55](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjsuZPJubbYAhUO3KQKHTqOBRcQFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ac.cn%2Fkyry%2Fhcc%2Fhccteach%2F201512%2FP020160615514232188602.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1OdsZe8ebz-CETY9hhBSuf). As well it should stressed out that your version is more general than the following version of Hardy inequality here: [Hardy's Inequality for Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83946/hardys-inequality-for-integrals)
and it is a third part version of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586845/bigg-int-0-infty-int-0xftdtpx-b-1dx-bigg1-p-le-p-b) from which it sufficed to set  $$ f(t) = \frac{g(1/x)}{x^2}$$ to deduce your version.

Comment: It is the exercise of my text book :Classical Fourier Analysis of Loukas Grafakos.

Comment: @user1992 I am a fan of that book too I see which exercise you mean they gave some hint right?

Comment: Yes,but I think just use change of variable and  Minkowski will work so, I try to do .

Comment: @user1992 see the update

Comment: You are right .