# Show that $ Tf $ is continuous and measurable on a Hilbert space $H=L_2((0,\infty))$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Let H be a Hilbert space $H=L_2(0,\infty), dt) $ with $dt$ the Lebegues measure.

For each    $ f \epsilon \ H $, define the function $ Tf:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ by $(Tf) (s) = \frac{1}{s}\int_{(0,s)}f(t) dt  , s>0  $

Show that each $f \epsilon H $ is continuous and measurable.

Can someone help me how I can show this?

Comment: Use the dominated convergence theorem and note that $\int_{(0,s)}dt=\int1_{(a,b)}dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following argument is for the continuity of the linear operator $T$, I misunderstood the question.
\begin{align*}
\|Tf\|_{L^{2}}&=\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{s^{2}}\left|\int_{0}^{s}f(t)dt\right|^{2}ds\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq 2\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(t)|^{2}dt\right)^{1/2}\\
&=2\|f\|_{L^{2}},
\end{align*}
so $\|T\|_{L^{2}\rightarrow L^{2}}\leq 2<\infty$, hence $T$ is bounded and hence continuous. Note that [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality) is used for the inequality. Look up this one for a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586845/bigg-int-0-infty-int-0xftdtpx-b-1dx-bigg1-p-le-p-b).

**The following argument is for the continuity of the function $Tf$.**

Consider a fixed $s_{0}\in(0,\infty)$, then $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{s}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\chi_{(0,s)}(t)f(t)dt$, then $\chi_{(0,s)}(t)|f(t)|\leq\chi_{(0,s_{0}+1)}(t)|f(t)|$ for all $s<s_{0}+1$, and $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\chi_{(0,s_{0}+1)}(t)|f(t)|dt\leq\left(\int_{0}^{s_{0}+1}|f(t)|^{2}dt\right)^{1/2}(s_{0}+1)^{1/2}<\infty$. Now $\chi_{(0,s)}(t)f(t)\rightarrow\chi_{(0,s_{0})}(t)f(t)$ a.e., so the rest is by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Thanks. I have on question. Would it be more clearer if I'd define the sequence $s_n := s - \frac{1}{n}$ instead of working with $s_0+1$.

Apart from that, I think that proof definetly makes sense and is really helpful.

Comment: If you take $s_{n}=s-1/n$, then this is just a sequence which converges to $s$, but by the very definition of continuity, if you want to switch to sequential characterisation, the sequence should be arbitrary, not a fixed sequence like $s_{n}=s-1/n$.

Comment: The virtue of setting $s_{0}+1$ is that, for arbitrary sequence $\{s_{n}\}$ that $s_{n}\rightarrow s_{0}$, then for large $n$, $s_{n}<s_{0}+1$, so the sequence of functions $\chi_{(0,s_{n})}(\cdot)|f(\cdot)|$ can be controlled by the independent integrable function $\chi_{(0,s_{0}+1)}(\cdot)|f(\cdot)|$ of $n$, then Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem goes through.