# When is $\Vert \Vert f \Vert_p \Vert_q \leq \Vert\Vert f\Vert_q\Vert_p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, holder-inequality

Under which condition on two positive real numbers $p,q$ (not necessarily Hölder-conjugated) holds the following inequality for functions where the integral exists?
$$\left(\int_{\Omega_1} \left( \int_{\Omega_2} \vert f(s,t)\vert^p d\mu(s)\right)^{\frac{q}{p}} d\nu(t)\right)^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq
\left(\int_{\Omega_2} \left( \int_{\Omega_1} \vert f(s,t)\vert^q d\nu(t)\right)^{\frac{p}{q}} d\mu(s)\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
For $p=q$ this is Fubini. Furthermore, if $f(s,t)=g(s)h(t)$ we also have equality. My conjecture is that this holds for $p\leq q$ but I have not found a way to prove it yet. I have in particular tried the case $p=1$ and then applying Hölder's inequality but I did not reach any conclusion. Any hint on how to get started is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Write $F(s, t) = |f(s, t)|^p$ and $\alpha=q/p \geq 1$. Then it boils down to showing

$$ \left( \int_{\Omega_1} \left( \int_{\Omega_2} F(s, t) \, \mu(ds) \right)^{\alpha} \, \nu(dt) \right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}
\leq \int_{\Omega_2} \left( \int_{\Omega_1} F(s, t)^{\alpha} \, \nu(dt) \right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \, \mu(ds). \tag{*}$$

Note that this is the content of [*Minkowski's integral inequality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski's_integral_inequality). One proof strategy is to utilize the duality between $L^p$-spaces. Indeed, let $\beta$ be such that $\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}=1$ and consider the operator $T$ on $L^{\beta}(\nu)$ defined by

$$ T\varphi = \int_{\Omega_1} G(t)\varphi(t) \, \nu(dt), \qquad G(\cdot) = \int_{\Omega_2} F(s, \cdot) \, \mu(ds). $$

By the duality, the operator norm of $\|T\|$ is exactly

$$ \|T\|
= \left\| G \right\|_{L^{\alpha}(\nu)}
= \text{[LHS of (*)]}. $$

On the other hand, by Fubini's theorem followed by Hölder's inequality,

\begin{align*}
|T\varphi|
&=\left| \int_{\Omega_2} \int_{\Omega_1} F(s, t)\varphi(t) \, \nu(dt)\mu(ds)\right| \\
&\leq \int_{\Omega_2} \| F(s , \cdot)\|_{L^{\alpha}(\nu)} \|\varphi\|_{L^{\beta}(\nu)} \, \mu(ds) \\
&= \left( \int_{\Omega_2} \| F(s , \cdot)\|_{L^{\alpha}(\nu)} \, \mu(ds) \right)\|\varphi\|_{L^{\beta}(\nu)}
\end{align*}

So it follows that

$$ \|T\| \leq \int_{\Omega_2} \| F(s , \cdot)\|_{L^{\alpha}(\nu)} \, \mu(ds) = \text{[RHS of (*)]} $$

and the inequality $\text{(*)}$ holds.

Comment: (+1) I believe my answer may be similar, but I explicitly use the [Converse Hölder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Extremal_equality).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $p\le q$ and letting $g(s,t)=|f(s,t)|^p$ and $\frac1r+\frac pq=1$, this is equivalent to
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\int_{\Omega_1}\left(\int_{\Omega_2}g(s,t)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s)\right)^{q/p}\,\mathrm{d}\nu(t)\right)^{p/q}
&=\sup_{\|h\|_r=1}\int_{\Omega_1}\int_{\Omega_2}g(s,t)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s)\,h(t)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(t)\tag1\\
&=\sup_{\|h\|_r=1}\int_{\Omega_2}\int_{\Omega_1}g(s,t)\,h(t)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(t)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s)\tag2\\
&\le\int_{\Omega_2}\sup_{\|h\|_r=1}\int_{\Omega_1}g(s,t)\,h(t)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(t)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s)\tag3\\
&=\int_{\Omega_2}\left(\int_{\Omega_1}g(s,t)^{q/p}\,\mathrm{d}\nu(t)\right)^{p/q}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: [Converse Hölder Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Extremal_equality)
$(2)$: [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)
$(3)$: an $h$ for each $s$ is at least as big as one $h$ for all $s$
$(4)$: [Hölder's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality)

Comment: Found it! At the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2588384) is a similar proof.

Comment: This solution is such a clean use of $L^p$-duality. I like it. :)